# How to XCTAssert several compares at once?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have an instance with three properties. I'd like to verify all three properties within the same XCTAssert. Is that possible?

For instance, instead of doing this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(myItem.name, "John Doe")
XCTAssertEqual(myItem.age, 35)
XCTAssertEqual(myItem.deptId, 1001)
```

Is there some way to do it all within the same XCTAssert?

Comment: No. Was it supposed to?

Comment: @vacawama `==` for tuples only works because there are explicitly defined `==` operators (for tuples up to 6 elements) in the standard library. Tuples aren't able to conform to protocols, so they can't be made `Equatable`. `XCTAssertEqual` takes equatable arguments, which is why that didn't work

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? If it's important to assert all 3 things then just assert all 3 things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose this was your `Item` struct:

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let deptID: Int
}
```

1. Conform to `Equatable`, and define what equality (`==`) means for `Item`:

   ```
   extension Item: Equatable {
       static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
           return lhs.name == rhs.name
               && lhs.age == rhs.age
               && lhs.deptID == rhs.deptID
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write a test for the `==` operator:

   ```
   func testItemEquality() {
       let original = Item(name: "name", age: 0, deptID: 0)

       let differentName = Item(
           name: "different " + original.name,
           age: original.age,
           deptID: original.deptID
       )

       let differentAge = Item(
           name: original.name,
           age: original.age + 1,
           deptID: original.deptID
       )

       let differentDeptID = Item(
           name: original.name,
           age: original.age,
           deptID: original.deptID + 1
       )

       let completelyDifferent = Item(
           name: "different " + original.name,
           age: original.age + 1,
           deptID: original.deptID + 1
       )

       XCTAssertEqual(original, original)

       XCTAssertNotEqual(original, differentName)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(original, differentAge)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(original, differentDeptID)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(original, completelyDifferent)

       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentName, differentAge)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentName, differentDeptID)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentName, completelyDifferent)

       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentAge, differentDeptID)
       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentAge, completelyDifferent)

       XCTAssertNotEqual(differentDeptID, completelyDifferent)
   }
   ```
3. From now on, you can just check equality (in other tests), with:

   ```
   func funcTestSomething() {
       let myItem = Item(name: "John Doe", age: 35, deptID: 1001) //obtain item

       XCTAssertEqual(myItem, Item(name: "John Doe", age: 35, deptID: 1001))
   }
   ```

Comment: I'd rather not modify the code just to get a specific outcome in an XCTAssert.

Comment: @4thSpace Lol what? How else do you expect to use equality comparison, without defining what equality of `Item` is?

Comment: If what you propose is the only solution, I guess I won't.

Comment: @4thSpace I mean you could make your own static "AssertItemsEqual" method, but that would be exactly the same as the `==` operator... What's your issue with the Equality extension?

Comment: Because like I said, it will ever only be used in an XCTAssert. I don't need the additional, unnecessary scaffolding in production code. Especially for every class I want it to work.

Comment: @4thSpace It depends on how often you use it. Equality its a really common thing to have, so you'll typically need tt anyway. And what do you mean "unnecessary scaffolding in production code"? I never said anything about making changes to non-test code lol.

Comment: @4thSpace The extension can reside in the test module, and be made `internal` to that module

Comment: Ah - I'll have to try that. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142434/discussion-between-alexander-and-4thspace).